# How to merge many rows with the same ID with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need the help from the community to solve the following problem that I found (I'm using SQL Server):

I have two tables, `USER` and `INFO`.

USER:

```
ID    NAME
----------
AAA   John
BBB   Mike
```

INFO:

```
ID      CONTANCT_INFO    CONTACT_DESC
-------------------------------------
AAA        111111           Phone
AAA        222222           Mobile
AAA    aaa@example.com      Email
AAA    bbb@example.com      Email
BBB        333333           Phone
BBB    ccc@example.com      Email
BBB    ddd@example.com      Email
BBB    eee@example.com      Email
BBB        444444           Phone
BBB        555555           Mobile
```

I want to merge the info table per user in one row as follows:

```
ID  NAME    Phone1  Phone2  Phone3  Email1          Email2          Email3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AAA John    111111  222222          aaa@example.com bbb@example.com 
BBB Mike    333333  444444  555555  ccc@example.com ddd@example.com eee@example.com
```

I've been trying many options and also surfing through stackoverflow posts, but without any results to my situation.

Thanks in advance!

Kind regards,

Aovon.

Comment: You must search about PIVOT and UNPIVOT functions, but... what would happen if there is a fourth register for AAA in INFO table? Do you want another field called Phone4? This could be a problem, you should fix a limit for the fields.

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for the response, the limit for phones are 3 and also for the emails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure that there will be only 3 phones and emails then following query will work:

```
;with PivotData as
(
select I.id,
       U.Name,
       I.CONTANCT_INFO,
       Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,'Mobile','Phone') + '_'+
       cast( row_number() over (partition by I.id,
                                Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,'Mobile','Phone') 
                                order by (Select null))--change here for sort order
       as char(1)) as CONTACT_DESC_Attribute
From Info I 
join [User] U on U.id = I.Id

)
SELECT id,Name,[Phone_1],[Phone_2],[Phone_3],
       [Email_1],[Email_2],[Email_3]
FROM PivotData
  PIVOT( Max(CONTANCT_INFO)
    FOR CONTACT_DESC_Attribute IN ([Phone_1],[Phone_2],[Phone_3],
                                   [Email_1],[Email_2],[Email_3]) ) AS P;
```

[Sample code here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5b37ecc537a995d6f83009399db066f6)

Use dynamic query for pivoting as:

```
 DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' 
                   + QUOTENAME(Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,'Mobile','Phone') + '_'+
                               cast( row_number() over (partition by I.id,
                                Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,'Mobile','Phone') 
                                order by (Select null))--change here for sort order
                      as char(1))) 
            FROM Info I
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT id,Name, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
               select I.id,
                      U.Name,
                      I.CONTANCT_INFO,
                      Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,''Mobile'',''Phone'') + ''_''+
                      cast( row_number() over (partition by I.id,
                                Replace(I.CONTACT_DESC,''Mobile'',''Phone'') 
                                order by (Select null))--change here for sort order
                      as char(1)) as CONTACT_DESC_Attribute
                From Info I 
                join [User] U on U.id = I.Id

           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(CONTANCT_INFO)
                for CONTACT_DESC_Attribute in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '
            
execute(@query);
```

[Sample code here..](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ffa5af7abf3a0a8e286160dcab43bfcd)

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: Thanks @Deepshikha, the first query using PIVOT has solved my problem. Thank you so much, really appreciated. Kind regards!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to consider. You may want to change the column naming/numbering method to meet your needs, but the output is what you're looking for.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#USER') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #USER
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#INFO') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #INFO

CREATE TABLE #USER
(
ID      VARCHAR(10)
,NAME   VARCHAR(10)
)

CREATE TABLE #INFO
(
iPOS            INT IDENTITY (1,1)
,ID             VARCHAR(10)
,CONTACT_INFO   VARCHAR(100)
,CONTACT_DESC   VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO #USER
(ID, NAME)
SELECT 'AAA', 'JOHN'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', 'MIKE'


INSERT INTO #INFO
(ID, CONTACT_INFO, CONTACT_DESC)
SELECT 'AAA', '111111', 'Phone'
UNION
SELECT 'AAA', '222222', 'Mobile'
UNION
SELECT 'AAA', 'aaa@example.com', 'Email'
UNION
SELECT 'AAA', 'bbb@example.com', 'Email'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', '333333', 'Phone'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', 'ccc@example.com', 'Email'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', 'ddd@example.com', 'Email'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', 'eee@example.com', 'Email'
UNION
SELECT 'BBB', '444444', 'Phone'
UNION 
SELECT 'BBB', '555555', 'Mobile'

UPDATE A
SET CONTACT_DESC = CONTACT_DESC + CAST(iPOS AS VARCHAR)
FROM #INFO A

DECLARE @COL_NAME       VARCHAR(2000) = ''
DECLARE @SQL            NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @COL_NAME = STUFF(( SELECT 
                        '], [' + CONTACT_DESC 
                        FROM (
                                SELECT 
                                    CONTACT_DESC
                                FROM #INFO A
                        ) AS x
                        ORDER BY 1
                        FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 2, '') + ']'

SET @SQL = 'SELECT ID, NAME, ' + @COL_NAME + '  
            FROM (
              SELECT
                     U.ID, U.NAME, I.CONTACT_INFO, I.CONTACT_DESC
                FROM #USER U
                    INNER JOIN #INFO I
                        ON U.ID = I.ID
            ) AS j
            PIVOT
            (
            MAX(CONTACT_INFO) 
            FOR CONTACT_DESC IN ('
              + @COL_NAME
              + ')
            ) AS S
            '
PRINT @sql
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

This has an output of the following:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tim for your response, I will take a look into your proposal too. Kind regards!